# How to stop an GCP instance with Terraform, or create them stopped

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Today I was working on my turbo mode GCP setup and stumbled with the following situation:

In the way it's right now, if I run `terraform plan` then the plan will show that the instance must be replaced, or recreated. I've set up a variable to pass in the command that I want to stop the instance. That variable turns into the `desired_status`. If I try to `plan` or `apply` with `desired_status` set up as `STOPPED` then terraform throws me this error:

```
google_compute_instance.vps: Refreshing state... [id=projects/artimanhas-do-lucaum/zones/us-central1-a/instances/vps]
╷
│ Error: 1 error occurred:
│   * When creating an instance, desired_status can only accept RUNNING value
│ 
│ 
│ 
│   with google_compute_instance.vps,
│   on gcp.tf line 59, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vps":
│   59: resource "google_compute_instance" "vps" {
│ 
╵
```

For reference, this is my tf file: https://github.com/lucasew/nixcfg/blob/master/infra/gcp.tf

Everything else is working as expected. There are some stuff to solve with my erase your darlings NixOS setup but that's another not-so-related problem.

Comment: Not possible. You need other tools to manage their running/stopping state.

Comment: There is a dedicated function block setup to handle this case. Have a look [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/84d1902233de4efd5509e9825bf15ef9c7c40dc9/google/resource_compute_instance.go#L2223-L2240). On creation, only `RUNNING` is accepted as `desired_status`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to do that, even [if you create VM directly without Terraform](https://serverfault.com/a/1019136):

> Sadly we don't have feature to create VM instance without running it immediately. The best you can do is to add shutdown command to your [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

You could try startup script as suggested above, there is [an argument in Terraform for it](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#metadata_startup_script).